# Is there any browser or method to prevent uploading?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser

I want my network to be secured, so uploading ,attaching by mail or other leaks would be disallowed.

I tried windows firewall outbound rule. But it does force close all the connections. Not working for me.

Please guide me , if is there any plugin/addOn to prevent browser file upload/protocol or windows exploit to deny file upload.

Thank you for interesting my problem.

Comment: Even if there is a plugin for browser **X** another browser **Y** might allow that. Hence, you must look for a better solution, something on a network level.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like , Then I know How to Block browser Y and any N browser.

Comment: Search on Google  *Data Loss Prevention tools*

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to prevent information from within your network being transferred to outside of your network (i.e., to the Internet)?

If a PC can access the Internet from within your network (e.g., if it can browse the web), then preventing information leaking to the Internet is close to impossible.

Let me give you some examples of how data could be leaked:

### E-Mail & Uploading

This is what you are trying to prevent. It might be possible to prevent this, but useless as there are so many other ways.

### URL encoded leaking

An attacker could use any browser to access URLs in a form like this:

> http://attacker-domain.net/leak-some-data/DATA-THAT-SHOULD-BE-LEAKED

He only needs a special server which is configured to save all requests.

### DNS encoded leaking

An attacker could use DNS to leak information. By using any program on your computer that has internet access. Just make the program try to contact an address like this:

> DATA-THAT-SHOULD-BE-LEAKED.attacker-domain.net

This will lead to a DNS request from your PC to the DNS server. The request is then forwarded to the DNS server of `attacker-domain.net`. So the attacker only needs a modified DNS server that logs the requests it got.

### Encoding Data in Request Patterns

The attacker would need more than one domain/address. In order to leak information it could use the access pattern to these domains. For example to leak the word "hello" he could use a simple browser and access the domains he controls in a specific order:

> h-attacker-domain.net
>
> e-attacker-domain.net
>
> l-attacker-domain.net
>
> l-attacker-domain.net
>
> o-attacker-domain.net

Obviously one could also use a binary code, or have multiple domains meaning the same, etc. etc.

### Conclusion

This are just some of many methods that an attacker could use to transmit information to the outside world. Obviously one could combine some of these methods and also use encryption and/or obfuscation to make detection harder.

Therefore preventing uploading via the browser is more or less useless.